# Kubernetes Cluster auto scaler in hybrid setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, autoscaling

I am looking into the Cluster level scalability of Kubernetes using the Cluster AutoScaler. These articles ([1](https://dzone.com/articles/kubernetes-autoscaling-explained), [2](https://dzone.com/articles/create-an-aws-lambda-function-to-stop-and-start-an)) talk about the possibility of bursting from on-premise to cloud using the cluster autoscaler, but i am not able to see any instructions on how to achieve this.

Also [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws) talks about having the entire K8S cluster on EC2s and achieve auto-scaling using the cluster autoscaler.

I also understand that cluster autoscaler does not come with Kubernetes and needs to be installed separately.

So these are my questions,

1. Is it possible to scale (scale up and down of nodes) from on-premise to AWS cloud using cluster autoscaler or by other means?
2. If the above is possible, any reference links would be of great help.

Comment: so the real goal here is to move from bare-metal to AWS? How big is your current cluster?

Comment: @aurelius The goal is to burst from On-premise into AWS cloud when the load increases and scale down when the load goes down. In essence, the on-premise cluster is sized for the normal load but scale into cloud depending on the needs. Bursting into on-prem private cloud may also be an option.

Comment: I came across this https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler but not sure if supports hybrid infrastructure (on-premise and coud)